# vb.net upload pdf to mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, pdf

So I am currently working on vb.net. I've already done the image upload to mysql using BLOB data type. Now I need to upload pdf file to mysql. Wondering if the image upload code is the same for pdf.

here's my image upload code.

```
     'open file diaglog btn
Private Sub open_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles open.Click
    Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog

    opf.Filter = "Image File | *.jpg"

    If opf.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        AxAcroPDF1.src = opf.FileName
        text_file.Text = opf.SafeFileName

    End If

End Sub

'save to my sql btn
Private Sub save_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles save.Click
    MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=printlmun"
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(MS, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)

    Dim command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `forms`(`name`, `price`, `img`) VALUES (@name,@text_price,@text_img)", MySqlConn)

    command.Parameters.Add("@text_uname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = text_uname.Text()
    command.Parameters.Add("@text_price", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = text_price.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@text_img", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = ms.ToArray()

    MySqlConn.Open()

    If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Image Inserted")

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Image Not Inserted")
    End If

    MySqlConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: You know you could have tried this before asking. it would have take a lot less time than writing the question and wait for and answer

Answer (score 0):

BLOB stands for binary large object.  The file type in this case is irrelevant.  It doesn't matter of its a picture, a PDF, a ZIP file, etc.

Yes, the code is the same if it's an image or PDF once its in an array of bytes.